# Porque no se insertan los datos a la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

estoy creando un search engine tipo Google o otros motores de busqueda.

Sin embargo cuando intento subir los datos a la base de datos mediante formulario, el codigo echo me dice "Error" y los datos no se sube a la base pero la imagen si se sube al folder donde debe estar.

alguien me podria ayudar?

```html
<?php

 mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "busqueda");

 if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
 {
  $s_titulo = $_POST["s_titulo"];
  $s_link = $_POST["s_link"];
  $s_keywords = $_POST["s_keywords"];
  $s_descripcion = $_POST["s_descripcion"];
  $_simagen = $FILES["simagen"] ["name"];

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["simagen"] ["tmp_name"], "img/". $_FILES["simagen"] ["name"]))
 {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO latinsearch(pagina_nombre, pagina_link, pagina_keys, pagina_des, pagina_img) VALUES('$s_titulo', '$s_link', '$s_keywords', '$s_descripcion', '$_simagen')";

  $aviso = mysqli_query($sql);

  if ($aviso)
  {
   echo "<script> alert('Correctamente')</script>";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "<script> alert('ERROR')</script>";
  }
 }

}
```

Comment: En la asignación de `$_simagen` falta el `_` a `$_FILES`. Agrega a tu pregunta el valor de `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: me aparece Error: INSERT INTO latinsearch (pagina_nombre, pagina_link, pagina_keys, pagina_des, pagina_img) VALUES ('Youtube', 'www.youtube.com', 'Youtube social, Youtube, Youtube Music', 'Youtube', 'youtube.png')

Comment: La imagen se sube al folder por que move_uploaded_file() se ejecuta correctamente. ¿es todo lo que indica el mysqli_error()?